# OpenCV: Creating a histogram from a number of float arrays

Tags: matlab, opencv, histogram

I have a number of float arrays, and my purpose is to create a histogram for them. I want to get a graph of the values' frequencies - one graph per each array. and I need all the graphs to be shown on the same window, like this [Opencv example](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_calculation/histogram_calculation.html) does for rgb color histogram. I'm looking for a way to do it using OpenCv or to dump the values out to a file and do the histogram using Matlab. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matlab has a built-in histogram function - `hist`. It can calculate the histogram, or plot it, or both. For example, if `f` is a list of files with data you can use

```
for i=1:length(f)
  d=importdata(f(i));
  subfigure(length(f),1,i);
  hist(d);
end
```

(Of course, you have to tweak the data importing thingy to make it work. I don't know what the format of your data is in)